# Programmatic addition of child controls to User Control

Tags: vb.net, winforms

First time creating my own User Control and I'm having issues. I'm wanting to create child controls programmatically rather than set up ~480 controls by hand. However, upon implementation of the control in one of my forms, my controls I created programmatically do not appear, even though I call Generate and it successfully runs. (Checked with breakpoints)

Here's what I have:

```
Imports Syncfusion.Windows.Forms.Tools

Public Class InfoGrid
Private _Quantities As CheckBox()
Private _Names As Label()
Private _Toggle As ToggleButton() ' From SyncFusion WinForms Library
Private Beleren As Font = New Font("Beleren", 10, FontStyle.Regular)
Private IDInset As Insets = New Insets(5, 5, 5, 5)
Private QuantityInset As Insets = New Insets(5, 5, 5, 5)
Private NameInset As Insets = New Insets(0, 5, 0, 5)
Private ToggleInset As Insets = New Insets(0, 0, 0, 0)

Public Property Quantities As CheckBox()
    Get
        Return _Quantities
    End Get
    Set(value As CheckBox())
        _Quantities = value
    End Set
End Property

Public Property Names As Label()
    Get
        Return _Names
    End Get
    Set(value As Label())
        _Names = value
    End Set
End Property

Public Property Toggles As ToggleButton()
    Get
        Return _Toggle
    End Get
    Set(value As ToggleButton())
        _Toggle = value
    End Set
End Property

Public Sub Generate()
    SuspendLayout()
    For i% = 2 To 31
        AddNewCtrls(i, vbNullString, False, i, i - 1)
        AddNewCtrls(i + 30, vbNullString, False, i + 4, i - 1)
        AddNewCtrls(i + 60, vbNullString, False, i + 8, i - 1)
        AddNewCtrls(i + 90, vbNullString, False, i + 12, i - 1)
    Next
    ResumeLayout()
    Refresh()
    PerformLayout()
End Sub

Public Function AddNewCtrls(IDNum%, CtrlName$, CtrlEnabled As Boolean, GridX%, GridY%)
    Dim NewCtrlQuantity As New CheckBox, NewCtrlID, NewCtrlName As New Label, NewCtrlToggle As New ToggleButton

    Try
        NewCtrlID.Font = Beleren
        NewCtrlID.Text = IDNum
        NewCtrlID.Tag = IDNum
        NewCtrlID.Name = "lbl" & IDNum
        NewCtrlID.TextAlign = ContentAlignment.MiddleCenter
        NewCtrlID.AutoSize = True
        gblMain.SetConstraints(NewCtrlID, New GridBagConstraints(GridX, GridY, 1, 1, 0R, 0R, AnchorTypes.Center, FillType.None, IDInset, 0, 0, False))

        NewCtrlQuantity.Text = "400"
        NewCtrlQuantity.Name = "cbCount" & IDNum
        NewCtrlQuantity.Tag = IDNum
        NewCtrlQuantity.FlatStyle = FlatStyle.Flat
        NewCtrlQuantity.Appearance = Windows.Forms.Appearance.Button
        NewCtrlQuantity.MaximumSize = New Size(60, 25)
        NewCtrlQuantity.MinimumSize = New Size(60, 25)
        NewCtrlQuantity.AutoSize = True
        gblMain.SetConstraints(NewCtrlQuantity, New GridBagConstraints((GridX + 1), GridY, 1, 1, 0R, 0R, AnchorTypes.Center, FillType.None, QuantityInset, 0, 0, False))

        NewCtrlName.Text = CtrlName
        NewCtrlName.Name = "lblAssign" & IDNum
        NewCtrlName.Tag = IDNum
        NewCtrlName.MaximumSize = New Size(160, 25)
        NewCtrlName.AutoSize = True
        NewCtrlName.AutoEllipsis = True
        NewCtrlName.TextAlign = ContentAlignment.MiddleCenter
        gblMain.SetConstraints(NewCtrlName, New GridBagConstraints((GridX + 2), GridY, 1, 1, 0R, 0R, AnchorTypes.Center, FillType.None, NameInset, 0, 0, False))

        NewCtrlToggle.Text = ""
        NewCtrlToggle.Name = "cbMask" & IDNum
        NewCtrlToggle.Tag = IDNum
        NewCtrlToggle.MaximumSize = New Size(25, 25)
        NewCtrlToggle.MinimumSize = New Size(25, 25)
        gblMain.SetConstraints(NewCtrlToggle, New GridBagConstraints((GridX + 3), GridY, 1, 1, 0R, 0R, AnchorTypes.Center, FillType.None, ToggleInset, 0, 0, False))

        Controls.AddRange(New Control() {NewCtrlID, NewCtrlQuantity, NewCtrlName, NewCtrlToggle})
    Catch ex As Exception
        LogException(ex)
        Return False
    End Try

    Return True
End Function
End Class
```

Comment: Most likely, it has to do with the positions of the controls (what your code is not showing). For example, with two buttons, you can do something like `button1.Location = new Point(0, 0)` `button2.Location = new Point(button1.Right + xGap, button1.Top)` That is, define the location of each control on account of the previous one (+ desired gap).

Comment: Or, you could use a `flow layout panel` on your user control, when you add our controls to the `flow layout panel` it will handle the placement of the new controls for you so you don't have to explicitly set the locations.

Comment: Sorry, forgot to mention. I'm using SyncFusion's Grid Bag Layout rather than a Flow Layout Panel.